# ERROR: Please run 'az login' to setup account

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, devops, azure-powershell

I'm facing this error on azure Devops pipeline. I've a power-shell script which I've triggered from my pipeline. Here's the ps script:

```
       $rgName = "fdevcusaks04-rg"
       $clusterName = "fdevcusaks04" 
       $aksMcRg= "MC_fdevcusaks04-rg_fdevcusaks04_centralus" 
       $id= "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"

       
       $aksNodeVmss = Get-AzVmss -ResourceGroupName "$aksMcRg"        
       Update-AzVmss -ResourceGroupName $aksMcRg -Name $aksNodeVmss.Name -IdentityType UserAssigned -IdentityID $id
       az aks get-credentials --resource-group $rgName  --name $clusterName --overwrite-existing
```

The error line occurred on aks-get-credentials line;
**ERROR: Please run 'az login' to setup account.**

Here's my pipeline task in which I'm using azure_subscription which have fully rights on azure portal and I've used it in my pipelines which working fine.

```
   - task: AzurePowerShell@5
    displayName: 'Testing Inline script'
    inputs:
  azureSubscription: $(azureSubscription)
  scriptType: filePath
  scriptPath: '$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/Terraform/Terraform-Scripts/main.ps1'
  azurePowerShellVersion: latestVersion
```

After running the pipeline, I got this output:

```
    Subnet                              : 
      Id                                : 
    /subscriptions/8850e9b6-77da-4602
    -8959-4031d23fcc92/resourceGroups/MC_fdevcusaks04-        rg_fdevcusaks04_centralus/pro
    viders/Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks/aks-vnet-55374433/subnets/aks-subnet
    PrivateIPAddressVersion             : IPv4
    IpConfigurations[30]                  : 
    Name                                : ipconfig31
    Subnet                              : 
      Id                                :                 
    /subscriptions/8850e9b6-77da-4602
    -8959-4031d23fcc92/resourceGroups/MC_fdevcusaks04-        rg_fdevcusaks04_centralus/pro
    viders/Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks/aks-vnet-        55374433/subnets/aks-subnet
            PrivateIPAddressVersion             : IPv4
          EnableIPForwarding                    : False
      ExtensionProfile                          : 
        Extensions[0]                           : 
          Name                                  : vmssCSE
          Publisher                             :                 Microsoft.Azure.Extensions
          Type                                  : CustomScript
          TypeHandlerVersion                    : 2.0
          AutoUpgradeMinorVersion               : True
          Settings                              : {}
        Extensions[1]                           : 
          Name                                  : aks-agentpool-        26910569-vmss-AKSLi
    nuxBilling
          Publisher                             : Microsoft.AKS
          Type                                  :         Compute.AKS.Linux.Billing
          TypeHandlerVersion                    : 1.0
  Au        toUpgradeMinorVersion               : True
                  Settings                              : {}
        Extensions[2]                           : 
          Name                                  : AKSLinuxExtension
          Publisher                             : Microsoft.AKS
          Type                                  :         Compute.AKS.Linux.AKSNode
          TypeHandlerVersion                    : 1.22
          AutoUpgradeMinorVersion               : False
         ProvisionAfterExtensions[0]           : vmssCSE

    ERROR: Please run 'az login' to setup account.
```

I just want to know what the reason behind this and whats the solution of it so that I can run this.

Comment: What is the full output of the task?

Comment: error is at end line:
Import-Module -Name /usr/share/az_7.3.2/Az.Accounts/2.8.0/Az.Accounts.psd1 -Global
Clear-AzContext -Scope Process
Clear-AzContext -Scope CurrentUser -Force -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
Connect-AzAccount -ServicePrincipal -Tenant 856b3bd5-91fc-43aa-a9b7-14e215a9014d -Credential System.Management.Automation.PSCredential -Environment AzureCloud @processScope
 Set-AzContext -SubscriptionId 8850e9b6-77da-4602-8959-4031d23fcc92 -TenantId 856b3bd5-91fc-43aa-a9b7-14e215a9014d

Than output of first 2 Commands than:

ERROR: Please run 'az login' to setup account.

Comment: Please update your question with the **full**, correctly-formatted output of the task. Please do not summarize or leave out information.

Comment: @DanielMann Check now And if you know the solution, Kindly let me know...

Comment: You're mixing Azure PowerShell and Azure PowerShell. The stored credentials for Azure PowerShell aren't available for the `az` CLI -- there is a separate task for Azure CLI. Use the `Import-AzAksCredential` PowerShell cmdlet instead of `az aks`.

Answer (score 1):

I was mixing Azure PowerShell and Azure PowerShell. The stored credentials for Azure PowerShell aren't available for the az CLI -- there is a separate task for Azure CLI. When I Used the Import-AzAksCredential PowerShell cmdlet instead of az aks, It worked out succesfuuly.